# Why do we declare a @page = Page.new under new action, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This question is about Rails 3.2 and a bit more complicated than the title suggests.

Say we have a Pages controller, with all the RESTful actions. This web app can create pages, display, edit and delete existing ones, and list all of the existing pages.

Under the new action, I have some code like

@page = Page.new

So, when the user visits /pages/new, and fill the form_for(@page) do..end stuff, will the input data get saved to @page? For instance, if title and content are the page model attributes, will @page.title and @page.content return an error or display what we are seeking for? Or will the form_for directly save the values onto params?

If later is the case, why do we declare @page in new action? Is it there so that form_for could infer that Rails is about to create a new Page model object rather than an existing one?

Hopefully, that wasn't too confusing. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a form for a class just by writing

```
form_for :post
```

In Rails it is a convention to make a form with

```
form_for @post
```

because then you can render the same `form` partial for `new`, `create` (on validation errors) `edit`, and `update` (on validation error) actions. That's why you need to initialize an new "empty" object in new action - to keep the interface uniform.

Answer (score 2):

It's so that form_for displays ah empty page and the form_for ... because it has an empty object for reference ... can infer from the model how the form should be constructed.

This explains it in some detail...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Instance variables like @page don't persist after the page is rendered so when the form data is returned you'll be using that form data to create a new page object in your controller logic.

Typically if you can't save the new object because of validation errors, you will re-render the form page with the unsaved object instance, so the field will show the data the user entered and the user can correct any problems.